# rails accepts_nested_attributes_for can't update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

**I Using accepts_nested_attributes_for to update has_many nested tables, Why not update but insert**

**diaries_controller.rb**

```
def update
  @diary=Diary.find(params[:id])
  if @diary.update(update_diary_params)
    render_ok
  else
    render_err :update_error
  end
end


  def update_diary_params
      params.require(:diary).permit(:date,:weather,:remark, :diary_pictures_attributes=> [:diary_picture,:clothing_picture,:id,:_destroy])
  end
```

**model/diary.rb**

```
class Diary < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :diary_pictures,dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :diary_pictures,allow_destroy: true

end
```

**model/diary_picture.rb**

```
class DiaryPicture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :diary
  validates_presence_of :diary
end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzt9S.png)

Comment: Do you get any error message in your log?  Also, do you have your view code for diary?

Comment: no update olny insert

Comment: there is my log https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzt9S.png

Comment: There's an update on diary, but when it comes to diary_picture, it's not update, it's insert.

Comment: I've looked where I've used this before and only thing I can see different to what you have done is ":diary_pictures_attributes=>" which I would have done as "diary_pictures_attributes:".